# Проблема с кешем php кода

Tags: php, apache

Есть функция логирования (простая запись файл).
Выглядит так так:

```
logfile($string) {
//тут запись $string в файл.
};
```

В коде идёт вызов logfile('Значение 1');
В файл заносится 'значение 1'.

Потом исправляю код на logfile('Значение 2');
В файл заносится Значение 1 и значение 2. Как будто я вызвал 2 функции сразу.
Других вызовов функции естественно нет.

Явно дело в кеше кода. Мне надо его отключить для этого скрипта. На сайте включен opcache/memcache. Всё работает на Apache + Nginx

Не помогло:

- php_flag opcache.enable Off  в .htaccess  в коде.
- opcache_invalidate(**FILE**, true);
- перезагрузка апача, когда вроде чиститься опкеш
- unset($string) после записи в файл.

Куда копать?

Comment: Во-первых, [mcve], а во-вторых, попробуйте установить чистый сервер с нуля (например в виртуальной машине)

Comment: `//тут запись $string в файл.` а вот на этом моменте подробнее. Скорее всего вы открываете файл на добавление данных, а не перезапись

Comment: да, file_put_contents идёт с флагом FILE_APPEND, чтобы лог был беспрерывный, т.е. прстоянно дополнялся

Comment: новый сервер это не решение вопроса

Comment: Новый сервер - это способ найти причину проблемы и впоследствии решить вопрос. Поэтому по возможности попробуйте новый сервер